# robot test with selenium , Xpath not finding the element if special characters in Xpath.(Options de sélection)

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

Getting below error when we run the robot test cases in French , but it works the same test cases in English

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[contains(@class, 'v-button-caption')and text()=Options de sélection] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[contains(@class, 'v-button-caption')and text()=Options de sélection]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Running windows machine , changed the EOL(UTF-8, unix based) also for File , but not working .

Answer (score 1):

This worked after changing the and text()='Options de sélection' enclosed in ''(quotes)